# Why do I just get a grey screen when rendering?

Tags: rendering

I just started using Blender yesterday following Blender Guru's tutorials! Sadly, I can't seem to figure out why a grey screen keeps coming out when I press "Render Image" for Blender Render. Has anyone faced this issue before?

[image]

Comment: That can have sooo many reasons. Show more detail of your outliner, for a start, please.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! >< Yes sure, I have included some screenshots of my outliner & provided the file itself too inside this GDrive link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1DEmQRuFmyrtnxI65CCIk5-soMiSfDLOh

Comment: Hi! Someone has helped me & pointed out that my denoiser tab in compositing was the one causing the render not to show up. Nevertheless, thank you for your help! ><